# What do 'Me, OE', 'L.', 'GK', 'trans.' mean?

Tags: meaning

> ㆍ Christ learned respelling of
>
> ＜ ME, OE Crist
>
> ＜ L. Christ(us)
>
> ＜ GK. Christos, the Anointed, trans. of Heb. mashiah
>   (https://www.korean.go.kr/nkview/nklife/2010_1/2010_0106.pdf)

What do 'Me, OE', 'L.', 'GK', 'trans.' mean?

Comment: Where is this from? Please give us the source.

Comment: I think this would be a better fit for https://christianity.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Does this Korean document cite the English-language dictionary that it is quoting?  If so, have you looked in the dictionary's abbreviations section?  My unabridged dictionary has a list of abbreviations on the pages just before the definition of the letter "A", and just after the pronunciation guide.

Comment: Latin, Greek, Old English, Middle English, translation of Hebrew?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are abbreviations used in dictionary entries.  Every dictionary has its own conventions, and in paper dictionaries these are generally spelled out somewhere near the front or back cover.  As it happens, in this case the meaning of each abbreviation is fairly clear without such a guide:

- ME: Middle English
- OE: Old English
- L.: Latin
- GK.: Greek
- trans.: translation

Historically, these abbreviations were used to save space on paper.  Modern electronic dictionaries do sometimes use abbreviations like this, but they tend not to since they don't need to save paper.

The PDF you quoted doesn't give a source for the definition, but I think it's from an older print copy of the *Random House Unabridged Dictionary*.  In its newer electronic edition, the abbreviations are spelled out:

> learned respelling of **Middle English, Old English** *Crīst* < **Latin** *Chrīstus* < **Greek** *chrīstos* anointed, **translation** of Hebrew *māshīaḥ* anointed, Messiah

One convention which you didn't ask about, and which is not spelled out here, is the use of `<` (the less-than sign) to represent 'from'.  When an etymology says `A < B`, it means that *A* comes from *B*, and you can pronounce it 'from' when you read the etymology aloud.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe... ME, OE mean Modern English, Old English.

L. mean Latin.

GK. mean Greek.

trans. mean transform.

Comment: In this context, "trans." is short for "translation".

Comment: ME is **MIddle** English, not Modern English.

Comment: @dwilli OP answered his own question.

Comment: @dwilli I know, I apologize, I did not mean to object or anything. I don't really have a point. It was just a "oh, hey, did you see that?" kind of thing. I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: Thanks @AIQ, no apology necessary!

Comment: BigSilver your answer was flagged as potentially low quality by the system. There are also some comments that haven't been incorporated. I understand that it's your question as well, but it needs more work. Don't guess at answers - if you're not sure, then do some research. Pay attention to the comments and respond by using the information provided. Also, it's better to answer in full sentences to explain to the readers what you mean. Since you're fairly new to the site I suggest browsing answers with high scores to see what the community expects. Thanks for answering and please keep improving

Comment: @AIQ I changed the comment to reflect your input. You made a good point. Thanks.